# HttpPost Action Method In WebAPI Controller Not Working In .NETCore Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to insert into a DB using  WebAPI for a .Net Core  project but it's not working -

```
[Route("api/IMTWebAPI")]
public class IMTWebAPIController : BaseController
{
   [HttpPost("Create")]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] InterMemberTransfer interMemberTransfer)
   {
      var testController = new CRUDForIMT(_context);
      var response = await testController.Create(interMemberTransfer);
      return Json(response);
   }
}
```

CRUDForIMT -

```
private readonly ARMStocktradeV2Context _context;

public CRUDForIMT(ARMStocktradeV2Context context)
{
   _context = context;
}

public async Task<int> Create([Bind("Id,Date,EmailAddress,PhoneNumber,ResidentBroker")]    InterMemberTransfer interMemberTransfer)
{
   _context.Add(interMemberTransfer);
   var res = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   return res;
}
```

Anytime I test in postman, i get a 400 bad request and no response.

My Model -

```
public partial class InterMemberTransfer
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public long PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string ResidentBroker { get; set; }
}
```

I added a breakpoint in the Create action method but it's not even getting to the breakpoint.

[image]

Comment: Does `InterMemberTransfer` have any constructors defined?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @gbade_ provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Nkosi not sure what you mean by controller definition? The first code snippet is the action method in my controller

Comment: @gbade_ how is the controller defined? `public class MyController {....` You have not provided enough information for use to be able to help you. We are left guessing what the problem is because we do not have the full picture or at least the minimal amount that would be helpful.

Comment: @gbade_ Ok figured it out. The action is tagged with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`, which means it is expecting a token. Based on the postman image provided it does not look like a token is sent with the request.

Comment: @Nkosi getting unexpected '<' in postman

Comment: @gbade_ here is the crux of the matter. You are trying to access a secured endpoint without provided the necessary parameters. To prove the point. If you remove the anti-forgery token tag from the action you should be able to access the action via postman but then you have just unsecured the action. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Nkosi please forgive my newbie-ness, what are the necessary parameters I need to provide to access the endpoint? I did comment out the anti-forgery token tag and was able to access the action via postman but I am getting Unexpected '<'

Comment: Well then that is a whole new problem unrelated to the action but rather the data being sent. Try to pinpoint exactly in your code where that error is occurring. Try debugging your code

Comment: @Nkosi All I just want to do is insert data into a DB. I followed the tutorial to set up a webapi controller in a .netcore project and pretty much got a generated codebase. I honestly don't know what i'm not doing right as I'm following msdn and other tuts.

Comment: Do you have app.UseMvc() in your startup.cs?

Comment: @RichardHernandez yes, there's a app.UseMvc() in my startup.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` from your Create Method.
Otherwise you'll never get into this Method at all. At least not with Postman.